# Kendo Upload control is completed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am using the Kendo Upload control in a form and didn't want the form to be submit if the upload is still in process. I dont see any event I can use to let me know all files have been uploaded.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see a list of all events for the Kendo UI Upload [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events).

Among them you'll find the following events:

- [progress](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/progress) - provides you with the list of selected files and the percentage of the upload progress
- [success](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/success) - Fires when the upload has finished (can be used only in async mode)